# Receiving Emails with Google Cloud Functions in Firebase

Tags: firebase, sendgrid, mailgun, google-cloud-functions, postmark

I'd like to build an email drop service. Is it anyhow possible to receive incoming emails with Google cloud functions, process them and store them in firebase db?

I'm thinking of something similar to Amazon simple email service SES in combination with lambda functions. Does any of the available email services like sendgrid, mailgun, postmark or any other has api's to trigger Google Cloud Functions on incoming emails?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, services like [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/Inbound_Parse_Webhook/setting_up_the_inbound_parse_webhook.html) and [Mailgun](https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-receiving.html) allow you to set up webhooks for incoming mail. You can configure these webhooks to point to an HTTPS Cloud Function, at which point it will be invoked each time you get a new incoming email.

Comment: But there are no direct hooks yet or? Always need to go over https hooks?

Comment: Correct, there are no first-class event sources for incoming emails today with Cloud Functions.

Comment: Do you know if there is still no solution for this?